# How to enable (custom) admonition icons when converting asciidoc to html5 using the maven plugin

Tags: html, maven, maven-plugin, asciidoc

I use the `asciidoctor-maven-plugin(1.5.3)` to convert asciidoc files to pdf and html files.

**Problem:**

The pdf file that is created is rendered including the admonition icons - So, all is well here.

The html file on the other hand does not seem to be created in the right way - **the admonition icons are missing**. There is no text/caption instead just a strange placeholder.

I tried using the `:icons: font` [backend attribute](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/userguide.html#X45), where `font` is the only option I found in the asciidoc documentation.
(*By the way this is the same as adding `<icons>font</icons>` like shown below in the `pom.xml`.*)

The `font` option should show icons from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/ but it does not.

**Question:**

Do I have to import those icons form anywhere or dowload them and specifically include them using the `:iconsdir: path/to/icons` [backend attribute](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/userguide.html#X45)?

---

The important part of the `pom.xml` looks like this.

```
<configuration>
    <backend>html5</backend>
    <sourceHighlighter>coderay</sourceHighlighter>
  <attributes>
    <imagesdir>./images</imagesdir>
    <toc>left</toc>
    <icons>font</icons> 
    <sectanchors>true</sectanchors>
    <idprefix/>
    <idseparator>-</idseparator>        
  </attributes>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is embarrassing, at least one half of the story.

1. **The embarrassing part**

The actual mistake I made was using the `noscript firefox plugin`, which disallowed the use of `fontawesome...`.

In fact, I had to explicitly allow `cloudfare.com` in `noscript` to make it work.

So, my `pom.xml` stays with the attribute `<icons>font</icons>`.

2. **The good part**

I found out how to use custom icons:

- declare `<iconsdir>./images/icons</iconsdir>` (This is also the default, relative to the source directory.)
- copy some icons in it. I got them from [here](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/images/icons). (Pay attention to the names: `note.png` for `NOTE: This is a note.`)
- change `<icons>font</icons>` to `<icons>image</icons>`